# Simple Laravel Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, models, relationships

I have two models, one is LeadHistory and the other one is Leads.

Leads:

```
class Leads extends Model
{
    public function lead_history()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LeadHistory');
    }
}
```

LeadHistory:

```
class LeadHistory extends Model
{
    public function lead()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Leads', 'lead_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

When I go into php tinker, get the first Lead ($lead = App\Leads::first();), create a new LeadHistory ($leadHistory = new App\LeadHistory;) and ($leadHistory->message = 'second one';) and ($leadHistory->status_id = 11;) then try to save the leadHistory ($leadHistory->lead()->save($lead);). I get this error message:

BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()'

Can someone point me in the right direction, I feel like I have been following the instructions given in Laracasts but can't seem to get the LeadHistory to save with the associated Lead ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save `$leadHistory` first:

```
$leadHistory->save();
```

And then:

```
$lead->lead_history()->save($leadHistory)
```

Comment: getting the error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'leads_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `lead_histories` set `updated_at` = 2016-11-21 09:54:53, `leads_id` = 363106 where `id` = 3)' with your solution, using 5.1 I believe.

Comment: @DavidJarrin create `leads_id` in table of `LeadHistory` model. It will contain ID of a lead.

Answer (score 1):

You’re trying to call `save()` on a relation rather than a model I think.

Instead, “attach” your `LeadHistory` model to your `Lead` model:

```
$lead = Lead::create($leadAttributes);

$history = new LeadHistory($leadHistoryAttributes);

$lead->history()->attach($history);
```

You’ll need to rename your relation if you copy-and-paste the above code:

```
class Lead extends Model
{
    public function history()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LeadHistory::class);
    }
}
```

I feel the name “lead history” is superfluous when you’re already working with a `Lead` model.

Comment: getting the error BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()' with this method, should mention I'm using 5.1 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but since you already have a model instance of your target `App\Leads`, I think you should be able to simply access the id of that instance and inject it into a static create call:

```
$lead = App\Leads::first();

$leadHistory = App\LeadHistory::create([
    'message'   => 'second one',
    'status_id' => 11,
    'lead_id'   => $lead->id
]);
```

Before being able to use the `create` method you'd have to make the properties you want to assign 'mass assignable', by defining a protected property called `$fillable` in your model:

```
class LeadHistory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'message',
        'status_id',
        'lead_id'
    ];

    public function lead()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Leads', 'lead_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

This will effectively associate your new record with that lead, since the only thing the Eloquent model does in this regard is providing another way to describe the same relationships your database exercises.

Some other answers mention the `attach()` method of an Eloquent model. This method is used to attach two models with a many to many relationship (relationships defined with `belongsToMany`).